# How to replace typo3 deprecated Annotation @validate Boolean(is=true)?

Tags: annotations, doctrine, typo3

I have to upgrade a Typo3 v9 project to Typo3 v10.

Annotations like they were before are deprecated. I know how to replace something like **@validate NotEmpty** with  **@TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Annotation\Validate("NotEmpty")**

But I have some classes that use **@validate Boolean(is=true)**

As far as I can tell it means that the Checkbox of a form has to be checked and the validation is done in the model.

Can anyone please tell me how to replace this? Otherwise I think I have to code the validation in my controller class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `options` for this:

```php
/**
 * @TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Annotation\Validate("Boolean", options={"is": true})
 */
public bool $enabled;
```

See [Validating in the domain model with annotations](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/12.4/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/Extbase/Reference/Validation.html#annotations-with-arguments)

Comment: your link shows a 404 page